# Specifying a default target directory for cloning git directories

Tags: git

I have a folder (~/repos)  in my home directory in which I store cloned repositories from github. Is there a way to set an option so that `git clone <repository> [directory]` will clone  into ~/repos if [directory] is empty, and otherwise  will clone it into [directory]?

Comment: Not currently, no. It's been bruited about a bit as an idea, along with one for separating the Git directories from the cloned repositories, but nobody really likes all the consequences. Just write your own script to do it. (Such a script can be (a) tiny and (b) portable to anything with sh/bash so you'll be able to use it everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am a (self taught) noob at shell scripting; would you be willing to share an example script?

Comment: Use the built in `-d` (is a directory) test to see if a directory exists. Testing for "empty directory" is a bit more complex: you'll need to decide what qualifies (or disqualifies) such a directory as being "empty". For instance, you could fiddle with the [dotglob setting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339566/bash-moving-hidden-files-reset-dotglob) and then see if `*` expands to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get most of the way there by creating an alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.pclone '!git -C $HOME/repos clone'
```

Now if you run:

```
git pclone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/hello.git
```

You will find that repository available locally in `~/repos/hello`.

(And of course you can call your alias anything you want; I just picked `pclone` for `project-clone`.)

---

If you need more logic than you can conveniently fit into a `git` alias, you can instead create a shell script named `git-pclone` with content like:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec git -C $HOME/repos clone "$@"
```

Make it executable and place it somewhere in your `$PATH`. This by itself is identical in behavior to the alias, but you can add whatever logic you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I run `git config --global alias.pclone='!git -C $HOME/repos clone'` I get `error: invalid key: alias.pclone=!git -C $HOME/repos clone`

Comment: Sorry, in my enthusiasm I had a spurious `=` there. Fixed it.

Comment: No problem! Your enthusiasm is greatly appreciated!